# What is the use of Autoscroll property of JButton in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to java.i am developing application using netbeans and i found Autoscroll property of JButton.
I check this property but i can't understand this.
I am also search on internet but then also i didn't get information on it.

Can you please tell me this property in deeply and use of it in netbeans.

thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autoscrolls property is a property inherited from JComponent :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAutoscrolls%28boolean%29